# Prestashop Db::getInstance()->update() return Undefined variable

Tags: php, csv, import, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I tried to import my CSV file to update my products, it keeps give me time out and after 2 weeks, we ruled out the server is the problem ( we tried changing max_execution_time, memory_limit, or anything that we think would cause it)

The error logs showed following error:
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: return in /var/www/vhosts/22/xxxxxx/webspace/httpdocs/xxxxxx/controllers/admin/AdminImportController.php on line 1518

which is a customized code that we added to sort our products listing;
Following are the code

```
$prod_pos = get_object_vars($product);

            if (isset($info['position']) && !empty($info['position']))
            {

                $update_prod_cat_id = array();
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($product->category); $i++)
                {
                    if (is_numeric($product->category[$i])){
                        $return &= Db::getInstance()->update('category_product', array(
                            'position' => $info['position'],
                        ), '`id_category` = '.(int)$product->category[$i].' AND `id_product` = '.(int)$product->id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $update_prod_cat_id[] = Category::searchByName($default_language_id, trim($product->category[$i]), true);
                        $return &= Db::getInstance()->update('category_product', array(
                            'position' => $info['position'],
                        ), '`id_category` = '.(int)$pos_cat_id['id_category'].' AND `id_product` = '.(int)$product->id);
                    }
                }

            }
```

The funny thing is this code was working until we move the hosting to cloud hosting  then every time we tried to upload a CSV file more than 300 lines, it will just timed out and the error log will show the above error!

I am wondering if the db_prefix needed for Db::getInstance()->update()
But I read it will automatically put it when we use this instance.
I am not sure. I tried everything I though it would work but it's not.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

1. From what I see in the code, the varable $return is undefined on the two rows that is being assigned
2. May be the script really timeouts, but this can be confirmed during the debugging process. The code above seems OK.
3. The db prefix is automatically added in your case.